# Calling #selector @objc function through perform crasher

Tags: swift, crash, selector

I am calling a function through another view controller with:

```
perform(#selector(MainScreenViewController().test))
```

The action is called test and it is located in the `MainScreenViewController()`. 
Once it reaches this code the application crashes with the following crash report:

```
2018-01-20 13:24:46.800692+0100 Business Name[40750:3947268] -[Business_Name.RPLabel test]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fd444d03e30
2018-01-20 13:24:46.809915+0100 Business Name[40750:3947268] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Business_Name.RPLabel test]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fd444d03e30'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001127621cb __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010de9af41 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001127e2914 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 132
    3   UIKit                               0x000000010f5810bd -[UIResponder doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 295
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001126e5178 ___forwarding___ + 1432
    5   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001126e4b58 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    6   Business Name                       0x000000010d54edc2 _T013Business_Name7RPLabelC5setupyyF + 738
    7   Business Name                       0x000000010d54e705 _T013Business_Name7RPLabelCACSC6CGRectV5frame_tcfc + 325
    8   Business Name                       0x000000010d54e746 _T013Business_Name7RPLabelCACSC6CGRectV5frame_tcfcTo + 38
    9   UIKit                               0x000000010f3f3f66 -[UIView init] + 62
    10  Business Name                       0x000000010d5385a3 _T0So7UILabelCABycfcTO + 19
    11  Business Name                       0x000000010d53137c _T0So7UILabelCABycfC + 60
    12  Business Name                       0x000000010d538944 globalinit_33_2857E66F75A5DBE934F5CCD1167A060E_func5 + 20
    13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000011380f43c _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    14  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001138109c7 dispatch_once_f + 297
    15  Business Name                       0x000000010d538984 _T013Business_Name9mainTitleAA7RPLabelCfau + 36
    16  Business Name                       0x000000010d5389ae _T013Business_Name10setupTitleyyF + 30
    17  Business Name                       0x000000010d53fd1f _T013Business_Name24MainScreenViewControllerC13viewDidAppearySbF + 31
    18  Business Name                       0x000000010d53fe23 _T013Business_Name24MainScreenViewControllerC13viewDidAppearySbFTo + 51
    19  UIKit                               0x000000010f4fcaaf -[UIViewController _setViewAppearState:isAnimating:] + 699
    20  UIKit                               0x000000010f55b746 -[UITabBarController viewDidAppear:] + 115
    21  UIKit                               0x000000010f4fcaaf -[UIViewController _setViewAppearState:isAnimating:] + 699
    22  UIKit                               0x000000010f4ff959 __64-[UIViewController viewDidMoveToWindow:shouldAppearOrDisappear:]_block_invoke + 42
    23  UIKit                               0x000000010f4fdc4d -[UIViewController _executeAfterAppearanceBlock] + 86
    24  UIKit                               0x000000010f364d9d _runAfterCACommitDeferredBlocks + 634
    25  UIKit                               0x000000010f35330d _cleanUpAfterCAFlushAndRunDeferredBlocks + 280
    26  UIKit                               0x000000010f374714 __34-[UIApplication _firstCommitBlock]_block_invoke_2 + 155
    27  CoreFoundation                      0x000000011270520c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 12
    28  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001126e9a3b __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 203
    29  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001126e9214 __CFRunLoopRun + 1300
    30  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001126e8a89 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 409
    31  GraphicsServices                    0x000000011556e9c6 GSEventRunModal + 62
    32  UIKit                               0x000000010f358d30 UIApplicationMain + 159
    33  Business Name                       0x000000010d548637 main + 55
    34  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000011388bd81 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

This is the code in test:

```
@objc func test(){
    print("test")
}
```

Comment: try this perform(#selector(MainScreenViewController.test))

Comment: post the code of `test`

Comment: All of what you have suggested won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
MainScreenViewController().perform(#selector(MainScreenViewController().test))
```

Comment: The expression `MainScreenViewController()` creates a brand new instance of `MainScreenViewController` that is not on screen and has nothing to do with anything else in the app. That code may compile and run, but it doesn't make sense to do that. it's like buying a new car in order to turn on the turn signal, and then immediately abandoning the car.